# Last number in an array becomes first

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list

I know that's easy, but I don't understand how I should do it.

```
 1 23 29 18 43 20 5
```

to

```
 5 1 23 29 18 43 20
```

I think we should use for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count - 1; i++)
{

}
```

but I don't know what to do in it. Something like numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1] but it isn't working. I think there are some if checks which I miss.

Comment: Using a temp variable the code should do following : temp = array[0], array[0] = array[6], array[6] = array[5], array[5] = array[4], array[4] = array[3], array[3] = array[2], array[2] = array[1], array[1] = temp

Comment: Let me throw a question back to you: What do you think `numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1]` does? Will it copy/move an array element to the left or the right? And why would you think that? (i consider the array index 0 is to the left and the max array index is to the right)

Comment: @elgonzo I thought it would move an array element to the right but I'm wrong. Now I understand why I should use i - 1 (it will move an array element to the position before)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward way that comes to mind is a reverse loop.

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 23, 29, 18, 43, 20, 5};
int lastVal = numbers[numbers.Length - 1];
for (int i = numbers.Length -1; i > 0; i--)
    numbers[i] = numbers[i-1];
numbers[0] = lastVal;
```

Just looping from the end (after saving the last value) and moving "up" the values, finally replacing the first value with the last

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a oneliner:

```
var numbers = new[] {1, 23, 29, 18, 43, 20, 5};
numbers = new[] {numbers.Last()}.Concat(numbers.Take(numbers.Length - 1)).ToArray();
```

This creates a new array containing the last element, then concatenates it with the original array excluding the last element.

Comment: Clever, unfortunately the ToArray is a low blow to performances. (Not that this really matters here)

Comment: Thank you! Agreed, on a larger scale, memory usage should definitely be considered, and since this question is likely related to a learning task, it's definitely worth noting, but as you also say, the impact in this case is negligible.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is make another array of the same size as the original one, then assign the last element and loop through the array up to the previous to last element.

Something like this:

```
int[] original = {1, 23, 29, 18, 43, 20, 5};
int[] altered = new int[original.length];

altered[0] = original[original.length - 1];
for (int i = 1; i < original.length - 1; i++)
{
    altered[i] = original[i - 1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a left rotation to the table by six positions on your case and create the requested new table

```
 int[] myArray = new int[] { 1, 23, 29, 18, 43, 20, 5 };
 var newArray = LeftRotationByD(myArray, 6);
```

and your function for the rotation would be:

```
 private static int[] LeftRotationByD(int[] a, int k)
        {
            int[] b = new int[a.Length];

            int index;
            int length = a.Length;
            int place;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                index = i - k;
                place = length + index;

                if (index >= 0) b[index] = a[i];
                else b[place] = a[i];
            }
            return b;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to shift right:

```
void ShiftRight(int[] array, int count)
{
    var clone = (int[])array.Clone();
    for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        array[(i + count) % array.Length] = clone[i];
}
```

And use it this way:

```
var a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
ShiftRight(a, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help.